# Error importing firebase client SDK in Typescript cloud function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to import the firebase JS client SDK (to simulate user interaction) into a cloud function written in typescript but I keep getting some missing namespace error.

According to [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) I have set `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to `true` in tsconfig.json to pass the type check.

The error:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Error: Cannot find the firebase namespace; be sure to include firebase-app.js before this library.
    at /Users/theo/Desktop/flint-cf/functions/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:372:285
    at /Users/theo/Desktop/flint-cf/functions/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:372:388
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/theo/Desktop/flint-cf/functions/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:372:394)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
```

My code:

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
// This import loads the firebase namespace.
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

// These imports load individual services into the firebase namespace.
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/functions';

// contants
import { CF_LOCATION } from '../../constants/cf_config';

firebase.initializeApp({
  // my creds
});

export = functions
  .region(CF_LOCATION)
  .pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes')
  .onRun(context => {
    try {
      const user = firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword('blabla@test.com', 'blablapass');
      console.log('authenticated');
      console.log(user);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    return null;
  });
```

What am I missing here ?

Cheers! :)

Comment: Have you tried `import * as firebase from "firebase/app";` from the docs?

Comment: @samthecodingman yes, same error

Comment: I don't understand what this code is trying to accomplish. Users sign in on the frontend using your web or mobile app.  Signing in on the backend using Cloud Functions doesn't make any sense.  The Firebase client libraries aren't intended for use on backends using nodejs.

Comment: @DougStevenson I get the weirdness of how it looks. What I'm trying to do is to have this scheduled function perform actions as a user to generate fake content (create posts, comments, etc..) to see how it looks on my frontend :)